# how do i allow header "Accept-Ranges" in nginx?

Tags: javascript, nginx, tornado

I have an app working from localhost:8888 using tornado, and this is the headers i'v set:

```
 def set_default_headers(self):
    self.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.add_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Accept-Ranges")
    self.add_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Content-Encoding")
    self.add_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers"," Content-Length")
    self.add_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Content-Range")
```

the app on localhot:8888 needs to get a static file from locahost:80, 
and the nginx server on localhost:80 looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/statics;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_use_global_queue on;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin [http://localhost:8888;]
  add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Accept-Ranges;
  add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Encoding;
  add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
  add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Range;
  add_header accept_ranges bytes;
  client_max_body_size 512M;
}
```

but the error in the browser is persistent:

```
Refused to get unsafe header "Accept-Ranges"
```

i tried to add all those headers above after seeing this
[issue](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3150) where the concerned op gave as his solution making the static pdf server return the headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Accept-Ranges, Content-Encoding, Content-Length,
```

how do i achieve that in nginx and tornado?

Answer (score 2):

For getting static file with GET method you only need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to nginx. I have created following to show how to access static file from cross origin.

I have created a tornado server () which hosts a html file. I am trying to access a static file using javascript hosted by nginx

tornado server.py

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([
            (r'/', MainHandler)
        ])
    app.listen(12303)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p> Hi </p>
    <button id="btn">click</button>
    <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                $.get('http://localhost:12300/stacktest/abc.html', function(data){
                    $('#content').append(data);
                });
            });
        });        
    </script>
</htm>
```

nginx configuration

```
server{
        listen          12300;
        server_name     localhost;

        location /stacktest {
            alias D:/stackof_test;
            index index.html;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:12303;            
        }
    }
```

Please note that I am on windows and the location "D:/stackof_test" contains a file called "abc.html" with following content

```
<p>Got the file</p>
```